# npm install git+ssh failing in docker (node16)

Tags: node.js, git, docker, npm

Can anyone explain why switching from `node:14-alpine` to `node:16-alpine` would cause npm install to fail?

```
 > [ 8/10] RUN --mount=type=ssh npm i:
#14 14.27 npm ERR! code 128
#14 14.28 npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
#14 14.28 npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/(somerepo).git
#14 14.28 npm ERR! Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
#14 14.28 npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
#14 14.28 npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#14 14.28 npm ERR! 
#14 14.28 npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#14 14.28 npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

This is a:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com:someorg/somerepo
```

dependency. And the build is run using:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default .
```

I couldn't find any obvious changes in the [image](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/main), which makes me suspect npm (gone from 6.14.15 to 8.1.0), but I can't find anything documented (and it works fine, outside the container)

EDIT: the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM node:16-alpine

RUN apk --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add \
    python2 \
    make \
    g++ \
    git \
    openssh

# Download public key for github.com
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
    chmod 0700 /root/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

WORKDIR /app/
RUN chown -R node $PWD

RUN apk add postgresql-client
ADD ./service/package.json .

RUN --mount=type=ssh npm i
RUN apk del build-dependencies && rm -r /root/.ssh

ADD ./service/ .

CMD node ./app.js

USER node
```

the only change I made was the `FROM`

EDIT 2: if I update npm (to 8.1.3) in the node 14 image, I get the same problem. but running `ssh -Tv git@github.com` fails even in the working version, so I have no idea what dark magic build kit has been using up till now

Comment: I've done it several times and never had a problem (MacOS multiple upgrades and downgrades). What does your Dockerfile look like? Have you tried to delete all cached layers? Try to do clean openssh and git install before your npm install command by running `RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client git` and `RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: > Have you tried to delete all cached layers?

there aren't any cached layers, as I changed the first line. but yes, prune af

Comment: The `permission denied (publickey)` line says that you're using ssh (which you asked for, so that's all good) and that your ssh called up GitHub's ssh server (ok so far), handed over your public key (it's supposed to do that), and then got the answer from GitHub: "This key is no good." So your key's gone bad, or you're handing over the wrong one. Use `ssh -Tv git@github.com` to see what key you're handing over and watch the key-exchange process.

Comment: why does it work fine with node 14, but not with the 16 image?

Comment: > Use ssh -Tv git@github.com

this is a good idea though, thanks

Comment: Did you try to generate a new one SSH key? And what about run it without DOCKER_BUILDKIT env?

Comment: @grahamrhay because npm version change in alpine-16's image, and I'm pretty sure that this problem is related to npm version.

Comment: >  if I update npm (to 8.1.3) in the node 14 image, I get the same problem

yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to be an issue with npm8, and git+ssh

use yarn

Answer (score -2):

The problem seems to be the `chown`, moving that after `npm i` fixed it (although that was done first deliberately, as chowning all those files takes forever).

I have no idea why that would affect ssh.

Comment: It seems that this problem is related to npm version (that's why switching from `node:14-alpine` to `node:16-alpine` is causing the issue)

But I'm not sure that moving chown fixed your issue

Comment: I am pretty sure, given that it didn't work before, and did work after